# Why does printing time.Time and a pointer to time.Time have the same result?

Tags: string, pointers, go, methods, time

I cannot understand why the results below are the same.
I expected the first result is the pointer address.

```golang
func print(t *time.Time) {
    fmt.Println(t) // 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001 => it should be the address of t
    fmt.Println(*t) // 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001
}
```

Comment: You basically **cannot** use fmt.Println for debugging purpose because it does too much useful magic. Debug pointers x like this: `fmt.Printf("<%T> @ %p : %v == %#v\n", x, x, x, *x)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you print it using [`fmt.Println()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) which means the default formatting will be applied. And quoting from the package doc of [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/):

> Except when printed using the verbs %T and %p, special formatting considerations apply for operands that implement certain interfaces. In order of application:
>
> [...]
>
> 5. If an operand implements method String() string, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).

Since [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) has a [`Time.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.String) method, so does the pointer to it: `*time.Time` also has this `String()` method. So the `fmt` package calls it to produce the string representation of a `*time.Time` value.

Quoting from [Spec: Method sets:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)

> The method set of any other type `T` consists of all methods declared with receiver type `T`. The method set of the corresponding [pointer type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types) `*T` is the set of **all methods declared with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the method set of `T`)**.

All in all, no matter if you print a `time.Time` or a `*time.Time` value, its `String()` method will be called and whatever it returns will be used / printed.